# Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate... en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

Buen día, alguíen me puede ayudar como omitir por ahora este error desde flutter, estoy tratado de loguearme en la app, pero me sale este error y no me deja seguir con la autenticación, se que es del backend, pero por ahora deseo omitirlo, alguien me puede ayudar por favor, gracias...!

Error:
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate...

Código

```
Future<ResultadoLogin?> userLogin(String username, String password) async {
ResultadoLogin resultadoLogin = new ResultadoLogin("", false, false);
try {
  UseInfoModel userInfo;
  var response;
  try {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    };
    final msg = jsonEncode({
      "usuario": username,
      "pass": password,
    });

    response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http:------------aqui la url---------------"),
      headers: headers,
      body: msg,
    );
  } on DioError catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  if (response != null) {
    if (response?.statusCode == 202) {
      var resultadoJson =
          "El correo o contraseña son incorrectos, valide nuevamente";
      resultadoLogin.message = resultadoJson;
      return resultadoLogin;
    } else if (response?.statusCode == 200) {
      userInfo = UseInfoModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      if (userInfo.idTipoUsuario == "3") {
        resultadoLogin.resultadoLider = true;
        resultadoLogin.userInfo = userInfo;
        return resultadoLogin;
      } else {
        resultadoLogin.resultadoVoluntario = true;
        resultadoLogin.userInfo = userInfo;
        return resultadoLogin;
      }
    }
  } else {
    print('Error sending request!');
    return resultadoLogin;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return resultadoLogin;
}
return resultadoLogin;
```

}

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 gracias, lo tendré en cuenta